# How to keep a real time counter of specific page views using signalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am creating an application feature which keeps a real time count of the number of users that are viewing an specific page.

so far what I have been able to implement is that I can get a count of the number of sessions across the whole site, which is fine, however I would like to be able to keep a count of the number of users that are viewing an specific page.

the other problem I have is that the count is of the browser sessions, meaning if i have several tabs open with the same page then the count will increase by the number of tabs. how would I be able to uniquely identify each user?

C#:

```
public class View : Hub
    {
        public static int SiteSessionCount;

        public void ViewerCountChanged(int viewerCount)
        {
            Clients.All.viewerCountChanged(viewerCount);
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {

            Interlocked.Increment(ref SiteSessionCount);
            ViewerCountChanged(SiteSessionCount);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref SiteSessionCount);
            ViewerCountChanged(SiteSessionCount);

            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js"></script>
        <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script>

            var hubProxy = $.connection.view;

            hubProxy.client.viewerCountChanged = function (count) {
                $("#siteSessionsCount").text(count);
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to send a unique identifier of the users to the SignalR Hub. This way even if he/she has multiple tabs open to a certain page in a browser you will not be updating it as a view. With SignalR everytime you open a tab and connect to the site it is going to generate a unique connection Id. It does not know or care that you have about 5 tabs open with the same page. Looks to me like you have to allow the counts to be update but at the same time have the ability to filter out the same user who is running multiple tabs.